# Is std::array<T, S> guaranteed to be POD if T is POD?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, tr1, c++11

I'm currently writing a C++ memory editing library and for the read/write APIs I use type traits (std::is_pod, std::is_same) and boost::enable_if to provide 3 overloads:

1. POD types. e.g. MyMem.Read(SomeAddress);
2. String types. e.g. MyMem.Read>(SomeAddress); (This doesn't actually read out a C++ string, it reads out a C-style string and converts it to a C++ string.)
3. Vector types. e.g. MyMem.Read>(SomeAddress, NumElem); (This doesn't actually read out a vector, rather it reads out a C-style array and converts it to a vector.)

Overloads 2 and 3 are simply 'wrappers' around overload 1. (So if you're reading a std::vector or std::basic_string and T is not POD it will fail, as it should.)

Recently I wanted to use std::array for a bunch of reads and writes because I knew the size of the data I wanted to read and write at compile time (I was writing a wrapper around the PE file format).

I wrote the code to use std::array, and then intended to add another overload for detection and handling of std::array types, but I accidentally hit compile and to my surprise it worked!

I'm currently using MSVC 10 and it turns out that for std::array if T is POD then std::array is POD. (Which means I can just use overload 1 and it works.)

My question is whether this is guaranteed by the C++ standard or left up to the implementation.

I know I could check the standard myself, but I don't trust myself as much as I trust some of the language lawyers on this site, so I figured it would be best to get a 'second opinion'. ;)

Thanks

P.S. Code available here (it's a header-only lib):
http://code.google.com/p/hadesmem/source/browse/trunk/HadesMem-v2/Hades-Memory/Hades-Memory/MemoryMgr.h#86

Answer (score 14, accepted):

§23.3.1:

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the syntax `array a<T, N> = { initializer-list };`
>   where initializer-list is a comma separated list of up to N elements whose types are convertible to T.

In C++03, POD was defined in terms of aggregate: a class where every subobject is native or an aggregate is POD. So, by backwards compatibility, a C++0x `std::array` is POD.

Or, to be anal, one can compare the bullet-points of §9/5 (defining trivial class) 9/6 (defining standard-layout) and 9/9 (combining preceding requirements into POD) with those of 8.5.1/1, which defines aggregates.

8.5.1:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equal- initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Indeed the requirements in Clause 9 cover `array` as long as its element type is also POD and the implementation does not declare `operator=` or `move` inside `array` in addition to the specifications.

To be *really* anal, 17.5.2.2 says

> 1. For the sake of exposition, Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D do not describe copy/move constructors, assignment operators, or (non-virtual) destructors with the same apparent semantics as those that can be generated by default (12.1, 12.4, 12.8).
> 2. It is unspecified whether the implementation provides explicit definitions for such member function signa- tures, or for virtual destructors that can be generated by default.

The note in the pseudo-code for `template class array` is

> `// No explicit construct/copy/destroy for aggregate type`

Does `construct/copy/destroy` include `operator=` (assignment) or `move`? It probably should, but I don't think, by the strictest reading, it does.

Note that this "affects" not only POD-ness, but also trivial copyability as Johannes mentions.

Comment: Bah, these slender formulations in the Standard... Why can't they write things out in the committee :(

Comment: @Johannes: It seems to me there are more defects in the C++0x FCD than the C++98 FCD. What do you think will happen?

Comment: What prevents the implementation from putting a, say, `std::string` in `std::array<double, 10>` after the built-in array member, though?

Comment: @T.C. I don't see why not. You might file a defect report by sending a short email to Daniel Krügler.

Answer (score 8):

By definition of POD:

> **9 Classes**
>
> **9** A POD struct is a class that is both a *trivial class* and a *standard-layout class*, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). Similarly, a POD union is a union that is both a trivial class and a standard layout class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). A POD class is a class that is either a POD struct or a POD union.

[Emphasis mine]

`std::array` does satisfy all the requirements of being a trivial, standard-layout class template. So the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: How do you guarantee that the implementation does not have a non-POD member? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Potatoswatter found an error in my conclusions. C++ explicitly allows an implementation to explicitly define an assignment operator "with the same apparent semantics". This will make it a non-trivially copyable type. Making it community wiki...

---

<strike>It seems to me you don't want to test against PODnes, but against *trivially copyable*, which is way less restricting. Because that is how C++0x constraints types that can be used with `memcpy` and friends.</strike>

And while I don't think there are any guarantees about PODness of `std::array`<strike>, there *are* guarantees about trivial copyability, as the following shows (if I haven't got an error in the conclusions). As we know `std::array` is an aggregate, and aggregates are</strike>

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equal-
>   initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
>   no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

While trivially copyability is defined for a class that has class that

> - has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
> - has a trivial destructor (12.4).

`std::array` has no destructor (as a comment in the definition of `std::array` says). This does not seem to follow from the definition of aggregate classes though, even though the comment in `std::array`'s class definition claims that.

The remaining 4 requirements follow from the absence of bases, virtual functions and user provided versions for those 4 special member functions for aggregates.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't N3126 §17.5.2.2/2 specifically allow `std::array` to have a non-trivial copy/move assignment operator? (Of course, that would be stupid, but it would still be an aggregate.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter oh that seems to be the case. Interesting :)