# Why memset is not working with array container in c++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  array<int,5> A ;
  memset(A,0,sizeof A);
  for(int i=0;i < 5;i++){
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}

   return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, compilation error occured.

But memset works well when I use `int A[5]` instead of `array<int,5> A`. Why memset is not working with container array as either way is used to define fixed size array?

Comment: Why not just use `array<int, 5> A = {};`/`int A[5] = {};`?

Comment: Don't use `memset` on non-POD types

Comment: what is non-POD types

Comment: non-POD types : types that have a constructor

Comment: neither `std::array` nor `int` have constructors...
and even though I would also discourage `std::memset` here and rather suggest the `= {}` initialization, `std::memset` would work totally fine in this special case. the only problem is that `std::memset` wants a pointer as its parameter.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Much of the point of `std::array` is that it's a POD type. Still, agreed that `memset` is unnecessary here & should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Pay close attention to the declaration of `memset`:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

Notice that the first argument must be a pointer.

Raw arrays are special things in c++. You cannot pass them as a parameter to a function as such, but if a function takes a pointer as a parameter, then an array of appropriate type will [*decay*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a pointer to first element. That is why you can pass a raw array to a function that expects a pointer.

`std::array` is not a raw array, but a regular class. Class instances do not decay to a pointer. That is why you cannot pass an instance of `std::array` as a parameter of `memset`.

As explained in comments already, you shouldn't use `memset` to initialize `std::array` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`std::memset` should work fine with `std::array`. If you look at the declaratoin of `std::memset` you will see it takes a pointer to the array, that is why your code does not work.

```
void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );
```

This should work:

```
memset(A.data(), 0, A.size() * sizeof(A[0]);
```

Like others have pointed out, in your example it is better to initialize the array

```
array<int, 5> A = {};
```

Comment: Your use of `memset` here has a problem. `A` is an array of `int` and `memset` fills __bytes__ of memory. Passing `A.size()` is the number of _elements_, you'll need to scale it by the _sizeof an element_. Better yet, just use the `std::array::fill` member function...

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks, was not paying attention. Will fix the code. I know that memset() is not good to use in this case, but the question is not asking if it is good, it is asking why it is not working.

Comment: Your fix isn't quite right, `A.size()` is the number of elements so you want to __multiply__ it by the size of an element to get the number of bytes to fill.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Ups again :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`memset(A,0,sizeof A);` is incorrect. This is an anti-pattern. The way to set an object to all-bits-zero (for objects that permit this operation) is:

```
memset(&obj, 0, sizeof obj);
```

or if we have a pointer to object:

```
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof *ptr);
```

Your form happens to "work" for C-style arrays because `A` decays to a pointer but `sizeof A` doesn't decay. But for non-arrays you will get a size mismatch (or an outright error). Sticking to one of the two canonical forms avoids size mismatches.

---

`std::array` is not required to be implemented as a C-style array, so using `memset` on it is not appropriate. If you are creating the array you can simply write:

```
array<int,5> A = {};
```

If you need to reset the array later then you can use:

```
A.fill(0);
```

Comment: Is std::array a "POD" or standard-layout and if so, should it then be "memsettable"? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674247/is-stdarrayt-s-guaranteed-to-be-pod-if-t-is-pod

Comment: **−1** "std::array is not required to be implemented as a C-style array" is incorrect.

Comment: Additional info: C++14 §23.3.2.1/1 "The elements of an `array` are stored contiguously, meaning that if `a` is an `array<T, N>` then
it obeys the identity `&a[n] == &a[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < N`"

Comment: in the fourth line size of *ptr should be repaced by size of ptr

Comment: @DeepakY4-YrBTechComputerS no it shouldn't

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf your quote doesn't imply that `std::array` wraps a C-style array. In fact, see the next page after your quote where it says **exposition only** with note "The member variable `elems` is shown for exposition only, to emphasize that array is a class aggregate".  `array` might be implemented as some other aggregate besides a C-style array.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf another thing is that `std::array<T, 0>` is well-defined, however C-style arrays may not have length 0 , therefore `std::array<T,0>` cannot wrap a C-style array.

Comment: Regarding your last line of code, you might prefer to use the `std::array::fill` member function.

Comment: @Matt: the standard quote defines the `array` storage as a C style array. there is no implication, it's directly a C style array. size 0 is a special case, yes, and it does not imply anything (as you think).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It doesn't directly define it as a C-style array. It only says it must have the same semantics. Other implementations are possible. It goes out of its way to say *aggregate* instead of *array*.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: that's argumentative. and pretty meaningless. and attempted telepathic as to intent.