# emplace_back to std::vector<std::array> not works

Tags: c++, stdarray, emplace

I wondered that such simple program can not be compiled with gcc, clang and msvc:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> v;
    v.emplace_back( 1, 2, 3 );
    return 0;
}
```

Why do std::array can not be constructed from sequence of values? It looks pretty easy to write custom ctor with variadic universal references to effectively construct std::array from values.

I think it would be nice if std::array was considered a POD-structure.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The linked dupe doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Evg: What does it not answer? It says precisely what the problem is and why it can't be made to work (it's an aggregate with no user-defined constructors). It covers the obvious alternative attempt (passing `{1, 2, 3}`, which also doesn't work). The only question here besides those is basically "why doesn't the C++ standards committee do what I want?" which isn't a useful question (hovering somewhere between opinion-based and a defect report, neither of which below on StackOverflow).

Comment: The question suggests that OP already knows that. The real question is why `std::array` doesn't have a variadic constructor that would made `emplace_back` work. The dupe doesn't answer this question. Whether it is a useful question is a completely different story. Questions like "why doesn't the C++ standards committee do what I want?" are not always opinion-based. Far from.

Comment: *"I think it would be nice if std::array was considered a POD-structure."* That is actually the issue... `std::array<int, 3> arr(1, 2, 3);` isn't valid.

Comment: @Jarod42: POD isn't directly relevant there is it? [`std::array` *can* be POD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3674247/364696) (if no extensions to standard implemented), but even if it was, `std::array<int, 3> arr(1, 2, 3);` wouldn't apply. It's a wrapper around `int[3]`, not around three `int`s; `std::array<int, 3> arr({1, 2, 3})` and `std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3}` are legal on GCC, but `emplace_back({1, 2, 3})` doesn't work because braced initializers don't work through function calls, which use `std::initializer_list` instead of aggregate init, and only when the receiving type supports it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: `std::array` doesn't have constructor, and use aggregate initialization, and `emplace_back` and other construct in-place doesn't use `{/*..*/}` to construct object, but `(/*..*/)`. and `{/*..*/}` has no type, so cannot be deduced for `emplace_back(Ts&&...)`.

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to put integers into the `std::vector`, not `std::array<int, 3>` as you defined. It is not clear what `v.emplace_back( 1, 2, 3 );` is meant to do. Does it mean `std::array<int, 3>{ 1, 2, 3 }` as one item in the vector or does it mean `{ std::array<int, 3>{ 1, 1, 1 }, std::array<int, 3>{ 2, 2, 2 }, std::array<int, 3>{ 3, 3, 3 } }` or something else?